# Checking for vowel then display?

Tags: python

Trying to get the vowels and consonants to separate from each other.

Looked online for a while, no solution.

```
for x in range(0,(length)):
    if word[x] == ["a"] or word[x] == ["e"] or word[x] == ["i"] or word[x] == ["o"] or word[x] == ["u"]:
        vowel = vowel + word[x]
    else:
     consonant = consonant + word
```

I expect it to output the vowels and the consonants. it's just outputting the constants 5 times.

Comment: I guess you meant `consonant = consonant + word[x]`?

Comment: You never actually output anything. Please provide a [MCVE] with example input, expected and actual output so we can be sure we're solving the right problem (there are many problems here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    test = "AlfieBaker"
    length = len(test)
    consonant = ""
    vowel = ""

    for char in test:
        if(char.lower() in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')):
            vowel = vowel+char
        else:
            consonant = consonant+char

    print("Vowels: ", vowel)
    print()
    print("Consonants: ", consonant)

main()
```

Results in:

```
Vowels:  Aieae

Consonants:  lfBkr
```

Answer (score 1):

`for x in range(0, len(...))` is a relict from C-times, we (almost) never need this in Python land:

```
word = "foobar"
vowels = ""
consonants = ""
for char in word:
    if char in "aeiou":
        vowels += char
    else:
        consonants += char
```

After this, you'll get the expected result:

```
>>> vowels
'ooa'
>>> consonants
'fbr'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You are checking a character against a list: `word[x] == ["a"]`
2. You are adding the word to the consonants: `consonant = consonant + word`

A possible solution will be:

```
s = "vowels"

vowels, consonants = "", ""
for ch in s:
    if ch in "aeiou":
       vowels = vowels + ch
    else:
       consonants = consonants + ch

print(vowels)
print(consonants)
```

**Output**

```
oe
vwls
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "separatethis"
vowels = [x for x in word if x in "aeiou"]
consonants = [x for x in word if x not in "aeiou"]
```

if you want them as a string just use join

```
"".join(vowels)
"".join(consonants)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = 'Hello Python!'
vowel = []
consonant = []
for i in range(0,len(word)):
    word = word.lower()
    if word[i] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        vowel.append(word[i])
        continue
    elif (word[i].isalpha()):
        consonant.append(word[i])
print('Vowel list:',vowel)
print('Consonant list:',consonant)
```

**OUTPUT**

Vowel list: ['e', 'o', 'o']

Consonant list: ['h', 'l', 'l', 'p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'n']